# Paypal donation's notification going elsewhere instead of specified addressee

Tags: html, paypal, payment, donations

I have a question regarding paypal donation. This is the current paypal on a production site (excluding personal information which has been altered but otherwise identical).

The issue is that for some reason, it has randomly started sending the email notifications to the overall person in charge of the paypal's account here instead of specified email address written in the code beneath. And yes, the email addressee has received emails before, and is part of the paypal account.

Why would it suddenly just start sending emails to the overall account holder instead of the specified addressee?

Please let me know if there are further information I need to add. Thank you.

```
 <form action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post">

                    <!-- Specify a Donate button. -->
                    <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_donations">
                    <input type="hidden" name="business" value="email_address">
                    <input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="Donation Program">
                    <input type="hidden" name="lc" value="US">
                    <input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="USD">
                    <input type="hidden" name="no_shipping" value="2">
                    <input type="hidden" name="return" value="URL">
                    <!-- Replace value with the web page you want the customer to return to after item cancellation -->
                    <input type="hidden" name="cancel_return" value="URL">
                    <!-- Note: shipping override variable is used with this example -->
                    <input type="hidden" name="no_note" value="0">

                    <!-- Specify details about the contribution -->

                    <input type="hidden" name="item_number" value="Donation Program"> 
                    <select name="amount" class="typl8-zeta">
                        <optgroup label="Donation Program">
                             <option value="200">$200</option>
                             <option value="250">$250</option>
                             <option value="300">$300</option>
                             <option value="350">$350</option>
                             <option value="400">$400</option>
                             <option value="450">$450</option>
                             <option value="500">$500</option>
                    </select>
                    <input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="USD">


                    <br /><br />
                    <!-- Display the payment button. -->
                    <input type="image" name="submit" border="0"
                     src="https://www.paypal.com/en_US/i/btn/btn_donate_LG.gif"
                     alt="PayPal - The safer, easier way to pay online">
                     <img alt="" border="0" width="1" height="1"
                     src="https://www.paypal.com/en_US/i/scr/pixel.gif" >
                     </form>
```

Answer (score 0):

PayPal will always send email notifications to whichever email address is marked as "Primary" in your email settings on the account, no matter which email address you list in the 'business' input.

Comment: actually not true. If you handwrite paypal stuff like above, it can and does go to designated secondary account. Generated buttons definitely ALWAYS go to primary account. Plus, I've had plenty of other paypal pages that have secondary accounts listed, and notifications has always gone to secondary accounts. This is literally the first time I've had this happen randomly that it went to primary account, hence me seeking the why.